# How to have continuous ids for multiple models?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, models

I wrote my own billing software, but I don't know how to approach this problem.

Right now I have 3 models:

Number
Receipt
MilageReceipt

The point is I need to write two kinds of receipts to my costumers. But for the ministry of finance, they have to have a continuous ID over them. So Number just contains an auto field and Receipt and MilageReceipt just has a Foreign key to that. This way I have an ID over two different models.

But now I want to expand this to also handle multiple companies. So there are two different types of Receipts that need to have a continuous number, but there will be multiple users who all need their own continuous numbers.

I want to have something that results in:
Receipt: company:1, id:1
Receipt: company:2, id:1
Receipt: company:1, id:2
MilageReceipt: company:1, id:3
Receipt: company:2, id:2
MilageReceipt: company:1, id:4
Receipt: company:1, id:5
MilageReceipt: company:2, id:3

I hope it is somewhat clear what I want to achieve. Can you please point me in the direction on how to set up models to get this behavior?

I want to keep the admin as original as possible so I'd like to do this on the model level, not the views - if possible. Right now, for example, I create the Number automatically every time a Receipt or a MilageReceipt is created. So the user doesn't even notice.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For continuous sequences you really can't use database sequences.  The easiest solution is to have your own table (Model) to hold the sequences.  Here's some code I use to do that:

```
class Sequence(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Sequence'
        permissions = (('view_sequence', 'Can View Sequence'),)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    value = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Sequence %s=%s' % (self.name, self.value)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    @classmethod
    def set(cls, name, value=None, increment=0):
        with transaction.atomic():
            seq = cls.objects.select_for_update().filter(name=name).first()
            if not seq:
                seq = cls(name=name, value=0)

            seq.value = increment + (value if value is not None else seq.value)
            seq.save()
        return seq.value

    @classmethod
    def get_next(cls, name):
        return cls.set(name, increment=1)
```

To get the next sequence you would form a key string that names the sequence, eg:

```
nextnumber = Sequence.get_next('receipt_%d' % company.pk)
```

Since every company would have a different key, they will be separate sequences.

If you were to use this in let's say your Receipt save method, like so:

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.seq_num:
            self.seq_num = Sequence.get_next('receipt_%d' % self.company.pk)
        super(Receipt, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=False, Blank=False)
    seq_num = models.IntegerField(blank=True, unique=True)

    # etc etc
```

Whenever you save a Receipt, if it doesn't have a seq_num, one will be assigned to it.

There's just one gotcha here, which is that the way the transaction code is structured, there's a possibility of skipping a number if something goes wrong.  To avoid that, move the transaction.atomic() block into your receipt save() method.